# Jquery Select next nested nested nested input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to access an input that is nested in 3 spans.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar3"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Script:

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
  $(this).parent().next('.aadharInput .inner-row .aadhartxt').children('input').focus();
}
```

});

After entering 4 digits the focus should goto the next input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going far enough up with `parent()` or deep enough with `children()` both of which only traverse one level

Try

```
$(this).closest('.aadharInput').next().find('input').focus();
```

Comment: I was writing the same.. but you are quick!

Comment: What about `.next('.aadharInput')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code where you can check the length of input value on keyup and then find parent `aadharInput` and then find it's next `aadharInput` to get the next input

```js
$(function(){
  $('input').on('keyup', function(){
      if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr("maxLength")) {
          var $span = $(this).closest('.aadharInput');
          $span.next('.aadharInput').find('input').focus();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar3"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).closest('.aadharInput').next().find('.inputs').focus();`:

1. `$(this).closest('.aadharInput')` will find the parent `span` with class `aadharInput` where the input had four character
2. `.next('.aadharInput')` will then select the next element in the DOM which will be the next `span` element with class `aadharInput`
3. `find('.inputs')` will find the `input` element that has class `inputs`
4. `.focus()` will finally focus the selected input element.

```js
$(".inputs").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
   $(this).closest('.aadharInput').next('.aadharInput').find('.inputs').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
  </span>
  </span>
  <span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
  </span>
  </span>
  <span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar3"  />
        </span>
  </span>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
  $(this).parents('.aadharInput').next('.aadharInput').find('[type="text"]').focus();
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar2"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="aadharInput">
    <span class="inner-row">
        <span class="aadhartxt">
            <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="4" id="aadhaar3"  />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```